# Trigger oozie from shell script

Tags: shell, cron, oozie

I am trying to run a shell script which contains a oozie job; trigger this shell script from crontab. Oozie is not getting triggered !!!

shell script  myshell.sh contains

```
#!/bin/bash
oozie  job -run -config $1
```

crontab

```
*/5 * * * * /path/myshell.sh example.properties
```

Is there something I need to set in my environment or am I missing something!

Thanks

Comment: is oozie in your `PATH`? nothing else should be necessary I think. Why don't you use Oozie coordinator jobs for this instead of CRON?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing the -oozie argument to specify the oozie api url.

`oozie job -oozie http://ooziehost:11000/oozie -run -config $1`

you could also set the OOZIE_URL environment variable

```
#!/bin/bash
OOZIE_URL=http://ooziehost:11000/oozie
oozie job -run -config $1
```